# Why does Git push throw remote unpack failed error even though I have sufficent access

Tags: github, azure-devops

I am doing a simple git push from my branch to origin and am getting the below error. This is not with this branch but any branch am not able to push (even the branches that I created).

> ```
> Counting objects: 31, done.
> Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
> Compressing objects: 100% (13/13), done.
> Writing objects: 100% (31/31), 2.78 KiB | 7.00 KiB/s, done.
> Total 31 (delta 26), reused 20 (delta 15)
> remote: We noticed you're using an older version of Git. For the best experience, upgrade to a newer version.
> remote: Analyzing objects... (31/31) (26 ms)
> remote: Checking for credentials and other secrets... (1/4)
> error: remote unpack failed: error Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
> To https://microsoftit.visualstudio.com/defaultcollection/OneITVSO/_git/CSM-DIP-DAP-Others-AcquisitionFramework
>  ! [remote rejected]     users/pdamod/DenormalizedView -> users/pdamod/DenormalizedView (Object reference not set to an instance of an object.)
> error: failed to push some refs to 'https://microsoftit.visualstudio.com/defaultcollection/OneITVSO/_git/CSM-DIP-DAP-Others-AcquisitionFramework'
> ```

Comment: Did you execute git push command via git command line? And what’s the git version do you use? What if you update git to latest and push again?

Answer (score 0):

**remote unpack failed:** error occurs either your local repository may be corrupted or your Disk space is full in the server hosting.

To check your local repository is corrupted or not, First clone your remote repository to a new directory and then push again. If your local repository is corrupted then run **git repack** might help to uncorrupt your local repository. And if disk space is indeed full for Stash, clear them and push again.

Comment: Cloning to new repository did not work. Also others are able to push to same branch. There is not problem with disk space in server

Comment: was able to narrow it down to one particular file. Everyone from my team is facing same issue. Commit from VSO also does not work

Comment: If Others can push, Then your local repository may be corrupted. You should try to get clone remote repository to a new directory/Folder and push again. If your local repository is corrupted then run git repack.

Comment: Its resolved now. It was a custom code running on top of our check-in which was causing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

There was no problem with repo or permissions. There was a custom code running on top of our repo which was causing check-ins to fail.